# Parse error using yecc in Erlang: "syntax error before"

Tags: parsing, erlang

I am currently writing a parser with yecc in Erlang.

```
Nonterminals expression.

Terminals '{' '}'  '+' '*' 'atom' 'app' 'integer' 'if0' 'fun' 'rec'.

Rootsymbol expression.

expression -> '{' '+' expression  expression '}' : {'AddExpression', '$3','$4'}.
expression -> '{' 'if0' expression expression expression '}' : {'if0', '$3', '$4', '$5'}.
expression -> '{' '*' expression expression '}' : {'MultExpression', '$3','$4'}.
expression -> '{' 'app' expression expression '}' : {'AppExpression', '$3','$4'}.
expression -> '{' 'fun' '{' expression '}' expression '}': {'FunExpression', '$4', '$6'}.
expression -> '{' 'rec' '{' expression expression '}' expression '}' : {'RecExpression', '$4', '$5', '$7'}.
expression -> atom : '$1'.
expression -> integer : '$1'.
```

I also have an erlang project that tokenizes the the input before parsing:

```
tok(X) ->
element(2, erl_scan:string(X)).

get_Value(X)->
 element(2, parse(tok(X))).
```

These cases are accepted:

```
interp:get_Value("{+ {+ 4 6} 6}").
interp:get_Value("{+ 4 2}").
```

These return:
    {'AddExpression' {'AddExpression' {integer, 1,6} {integer,1,6}}{integer,1,6}}
and
    {'AddExpression' {integer,1,4} {integer,1,2}}

But this test case:

```
interp:get_Value("{if0 3 4 5}").
```

Returns:

```
{1,string_parser,["syntax error before: ","if0"]}
```

Comment: Could you show the tokens you get from the tokenizer for the different cases? It is the most important input for trying to understand the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the grammar rules what you are showing are the **category** of the terminal tokens and **not** their values. So you can match against an *atom* but not against a specific atom. If you are using the Erlang tokenizer then the token generated for `"if0"` will be `{atom,Line,if0}` while in you grammar you want a `{if0,Line}` token. This is what the "Pre-processing" section of the `yecc` documentation is trying to explain.

You will need a special tokenizer for this. A simple way of handling this if you want to use the Erlang tokenizer is have a pre-processing pass which scans the token list and converts  `{atom,Line,if0}` tokens to `{if0,Line}` tokens.